# pam_faillock and AD/CentOS 7.2

Tags: centos, authentication, pam, sssd

So, I have a CentOS 7.2 system and I used realmd to join the AD domain. I can do a # id {username}@{domain} which perfectly lists all of the AD information for that user. Awesome!

Using stock pam.d/system-auth and pam.d/password-auth files, I can ssh and login in as an AD user just fine.

But, when I attempt to use a hardened system-auth and password-auth, things get screwy. I have narrowed it down do the password-auth file, and specifically, the pam_faillock auth section.

Here is what I have for /etc/pam.d/password-auth

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        [default=1 success=ok] pam_localuser.so debug
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth audit deny=5 unlock_time=900 
auth        sufficient pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass audit
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=5 unlock_time=900 
auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=5 unlock_time=900
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

When attempting to authenticate, either on the console or ssh, I get the following:

```
Oct 07 12:07:48 vmcentos72 sshd[8406]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost  user=user@domain
```

If I remove those pam_faillock lines in the auth section, it works just fine.

Here is system-auth:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        [default=1 success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900
auth        [success=done ignore=ignore default=die] pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=5 unlock_time=900
auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=5 unlock_time=900
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

Any suggestions for getting this working? If only pam_faillock had a debug option :(

Comment: If you are using AD for accounts, do you need `pam_faillock`?  Presumably your AD handles locking accounts for failed login attempts.  Adding faillock to the mix can mix things all up.  If the only _local_ account logging in is `root`, I would say you don't need `pam_faillock` at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, the powers that be are probably going to want to keep faillock on. Unfortunately, the various hardening guides require it.

Comment: Well, that's usually how it goes.  I'll have to dig through some old stuff, but one thing I notice is no `pam_faillock.so` line in your `account` stack.  It should be the fist line of `account` with `required`.

Comment: `password-auth` and `system-auth` should also be identical.  Are they?  It's also recommended not to edit these directly.  For example, use `password-auth-ac` for your specific config and make `password-auth` a soft link to `password-auth-ac`.  Use the same logic for `system-auth`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you did not adjust the PAM stack accordingly, specifically the "skip" counts on the lines using the bracket notation.  If you're not familiar with that notation, RTFM **pam.conf(5)**, which also lists the bracket notation equivalents of "required", sufficient", etc.

The default auth section for RHEL 7 with sssd configured looks like this:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        [default=1 success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth        [success=done ignore=ignore default=die] pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

The `pam_localuser` line says the default action is to skip one module (`pam_unix` in this case), but in case of success (i.e. the user is local), proceed normally.  This is done so that domain (non-local) users do not generate a failed login attempt with `pam_unix` but instead skip directly to sssd (`pam_sss`, with a uid >= 1000 check beforehand).

Also note the **default=die** setting on `pam_unix`, which means a failed local login will abort the authentication stack right there (and not even try `pam_sss`).  Similarly, **success=done** does the same for successful logins.

As has been already mentioned, `pam_faillock` does not apply to domain users, but if you're using it for local accounts and inserting three calls to it around `pam_unix`, you'll need to change the `pam_localuser` line to **default=4**, so that domain logins will continue to work.  (With default=1, it will skip `pam_faillock` but proceed to `pam_unix`, which will obviously fail for domain accounts, and because of default=die, abort immediately.  Setting default=4 will skip to `pam_succeed_if`, as it previously did.)

I'm not familiar with `pam_faillock`, so I can't say if calling it again after `pam_unix` is proper, but if that is correct, you'll also need to do something about the success=done and default=die on `pam_unix`, or else it will never make it to `pam_faillock` to lock/unlock accounts.

This is a complex PAM stack; you might consult the example configurations in **pam_faillock(8)**.  Make sure you don't accidentally let everyone in (hopefully, the `pam_deny` at the end takes care of that), and be sure to adjust any *default=N* counts when adding or remove subsequent lines.

**TL;DR:** `[default=1]` means skip one line afterwards (`pam_unix` in this case).  Adding lines requires adjusting the count.

Answer (score 1):

This is my password-auth file and it seems to work OK:

```
# Setup PAM Env
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=4000000
# Check if Local User, if fail skip to SSSD part
auth        [success=ok default=4]  pam_localuser.so

# Local User - Load pre-auth, if fail end
auth        [success=ok default=2]  pam_faillock.so preauth deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900

# Local User - Attempt Auth, if fail end
auth        [success=ok default=1]  pam_unix.so

# Lcaol User - Sucess, clear lock tally, end
auth        [default=done]          pam_faillock.so authsucc

# Local User - Fail, update lock tally, end
auth        [default=die]           pam_faillock.so authfail deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900

# SSSD User  - Ensure uid is not system uid
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so debug uid >= 1000

# SSSD User  - Attempt Auth
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so

# Catchall   - Default result if nothin passes
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_faillock.so
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok


password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

AD user does not appear in the faillock output after a failed login, local user does.

UPDATE: I added some comments explaining the important steps in the PAM config. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you also have an explanation why that is so and which part of your config is essential to the answer and which isn't?

Comment: Essential part is correctly setup the skip function via '[success=ok default=4]' to a correct next module.