# pam_tally2 fails after password change

Tags: login, pam

I am running Debian buster on several PCs. I used the `pam_tally2` module to add some security to the systems. I tested on `ssh` and desktop login, and it worked very well.

So, for an extra layer of security, once all the PC were protected with PAM, **I changed the user password.**

After that, all good until I reboot the system. Every time I reboot the system or I log out and log in; then I got 5 or 10 or any other number of failed attempts even before I tried to log in. This let me out of the system, and I could only fix it by entering the system by using another account (or `root`) and edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` to log in.

As a provisional solution, I increased the number of attempts to 20, so I can log in every time.

However, either I am doing something wrong, or this is a bug in the module.

From my side, I only edited the `common-auth` file adding this line

```
auth    required    pam_tally2.so onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=600 audit
```

in the primary block, resulting in this `auth` list

```
auth    required    pam_tally2.so onerr=fail deny=5 unlock_time=1200
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure 
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so    
auth    required            pam_permit.so
```

Any idea or input will be appreciated!

**Second Edit** requested by the system to explain why this is not a duplication of "[Why does this PAM code prevent all logins to a Debian system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560196/why-does-this-pam-code-prevent-all-logins-to-a-debian-system/562703#562703)"

1. I already had pam_tally2 in the list at the top of the stack.
2. Also, once I managed to log in, the counter was set at zero
3. The problem only happened after changing the account password
4. Other accounts have no problem to log in the system (the password was not changed)

Comment: Daniel, I've just amended [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562703/100397) on the related link because I think I've at last identified correctly what's going on. I reckon that now makes your question a duplicate. Please take a look at my answer there and see what you think. (Notice the new part about needing an entry in `common-account` too.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this PAM code prevent all logins to a Debian system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560196/why-does-this-pam-code-prevent-all-logins-to-a-debian-system)

Comment: thanks for your help. No, it doesn't look like your answer in the other thread can fix this problem.  I logged in with another account to increase the number of allowed failed attempts and then I could log in with my account. Interestingly, the counter was then zero. . I would think it could be someone trying to log in, but this is unlikely since also happened on another PC without an internet connection. This only happened after changing the password, as I mentioned before. None of the other accounts which I did not change the password had this problem.

Comment: You haven't installed `pam_tally2` correctly. You're missing the `account` entry as described in my answer on the suggested duplicate, which is what resets the tally after a successful login

Comment: Now you killed me... I did not install specifically pam_tally , it came with debian , I just edited the file. The docs for pam_tally2 are not very clear. From your answer I understand it should be an 'account' entry in the common_auth file. I do not have that, but I have many files in /etc/pam.d one is common-auth, but also common-account. So, I am missing an 'account' entry in common-auth or the common-account is for this? Reading the common-account file I do have this line: account required   pam_permit.so

Comment: Don't muddle `pam_tally` and `pam_tally2` (or `pam_permit`); they're different. The documentation for either tally version is not clear at all. The obvious part is how to configure it for `auth`. The less clear part is the bit that you are still missing, which is that for it to work properly you also need an entry for `account`. I don't really care whether you installed it or just used it: the issue here is that it's not yet correctly set up. Please re-read [my answer on the suggested duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562703/100397) to see how to set up the part that you're missing

Comment: Does this problem still persist? If not, I guess it worked as expected and you just had too many failed attempts when the problem occured. pam_tally2 is designed to block any authentication attempts for the specified timeout even with the correct password. If it still persists you should check your tally count with `sudo pam_tally2 --user $USER` and check your logs if something else is increasing the tally. Adding pam_tally2.so to the account section is recommended because not all tools (e.g. [sudo](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707660)) use pam_setcred as expected.

Comment: @stefan0xC adding it to `account` is how the tally gets reset to zero. It's a required part of the configuration. `auth` increments the tally regardless of success or failure. `account` resets it

Comment: @roaima If pam_setcred is called correctly by the `auth` module it will also [reset the tally](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/a0d402a38d0f043861879b287ac6069cb8a7d4b9/modules/pam_tally2/pam_tally2.c#L784). This is also explained in the [man page of pam_tally2](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_tally2). `account` resets it when setcred fails.

Comment: It's in `common-auth`, used as (part of) the `auth` phase for everything. You can't assume `pam_setcred()` so therefore you must also put it into `common-account`, used by all the `account` sections

Comment: I don't disagree. I already said that "Adding pam_tally2.so to the account section is recommended" because this missing account phase most likely led to the problem in the first place (probably sudo tallying the failure counter by not resetting it properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In debian buster, tally2 is already part of the system but is not blocking anything unless the settings are changed by the user .
This is extremely easy.
You only need to edit 1 file:

> sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth

You have to add two lines. One has to be the first line after the comment #here are the per-package modules
add:

> ```
> ‘auth required pam_tally2.so onerr=fail deny=n unlock_time=m audit’
> ```

where n is the number of login attempts you will allow before blocking the account. By blocking understand that you can still try to login but the system will not login even if the right password is entered. And m is the seconds the account will be locked. After that you can log in if you introduce the right password.

The second line can be added as the last line of the file. Every time you try to login and fail or during the locked time, tally2 count how many attempts of login. If this nmber is >n then the system is lock. However to set the counter to 0 after login with the right password you have to tell it to the system:

> account required pam_tally2.so

Add these two lines and all will work